# Linear disjointness and algebraic extensions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, tensor-products

This question may have risen already, but I didn't find a clear answer.
So I was learning about linear disjoint extensions. Let's set the stage:

I'm considering a base field $k$ and two extensions $L$ and $K$ embedded into a
big extension $\Omega$:
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 & \Omega & \\
/ & & \backslash & \\
L & & K\\
\backslash & & /\\
 & k & \\
\end{array}
Now I know that $L/k$ and $K/k$ are said to be linearly disjoint if
$$\begin{aligned}
T:\ L\otimes_k K & \longrightarrow LK\\
l\otimes k & \longmapsto lk\\
\end{aligned}$$
is injective. Now this map intrigues me, for two reasons.

1. I heard someone say once that $L/k$ and $K/k$ are linearly disjoint iff $L\otimes_k K$ is a field. The implication $\Longleftarrow$ is clearly obvious, but is the reciprocal true in general?
2. I already saw in some notes that $T$ is surjective. Now I tried to wrap my head around this, and sampled some cases. The most generalcase I could find is if one of the extensions $L/k,\ K/k$ were algebraic, but I couldn't figure out the general case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first question follows from the fact that $T$ is a ring homomorphism, and therefore its kernel is an ideal of the tensor product. Were it a field, then its only ideals were itself or 0, then since the map is surjective, its kernel cannot be everything, then it is 0 and again we have an isomorphism, implying the second direction of your if and only if statement.

The second question follows from the definition of the ring homomorphism $T$. $T$ takes the tensor product of $a$ and $b$ into $ab$, now, take any element of $KL$, it can be written as a some over elements of the form $k_il_i$ for $k_i\in K$ and $l_i\in L$ by definition. Then the tensor monomial $k_i\otimes l_i$ is mapped under $T$ to $k_il_i$ and by linearity, a preimage of the sum over the $k_il_i$ is constructed. Implying surjectivity.